# What data supports what level of PPE should be worn by medical staff dealing with COVID-19 patients?

Tags: covid-19, infection-control

PPE ranges from a surgical mask, gloves, a face shield, N95 mask, socks over shoes, goggles, gowns and powered respirators.  What data informs us as to what is the appropriate level of protection that should be worn when looking after a patient with COVID-19.